# Is there a portable function like g_printf_string_upper_bound?

Tags: c, string, printf

In order to generate filenames I need to provide some buffer memory for `sprintf`. The size of these buffers was chosen rather arbitrarily in the past. This can easily lead to very nasty stack overflow bugs in the future, when  e.g. `int` becomes 64bit long but the string buffer size was chosen to be 10 characters only as this is the maximum amount of digits a 32 bit `int` can hold.

Some MWE:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mpi_size; i++) {
     //magic number: 32bit integer has 10 digits, 
     //+6 for "/rank_", +1 for null termination
     char path2[strlen(path) + 17];
     //This can possibly be an access violation, or a very hard to
     //find bug:
     sprintf(path2, "%s/rank_%d", path, i);
     //Using path2 to access some file
  }
```

Completely different sizes where chosen in other places, were people were very sure, that the `int` will not be bigger than e.g. 3 digits. This can lead to problems much easier.

What would be a perfect and portable solution?

I found the function [g_printf_string_upper_bound](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-printf-string-upper-bound) in the gnome library which would solve this problem elegantly and reliably.

Is there anything like this in the C standard, in POSIX or somewhere else?

Comment: snprintf is a part of C99.

Comment: Sure, but then the resulting string would be wrong...

Comment: You have to check the return value. If it's `size` or more, the output was truncated.

Comment: Exactly, the output string would be truncated. This will get me out of the stack corruption, but it will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although widely misunderstood, `snprintf` is designed specifically to provide for this type of situation.

The return value from `snprintf` is the length that *would* have been written (excluding the trailing NUL) if the buffer had been large enough to hold it. Therefore, you can use it in two steps: you call it once with an empty buffer to find the needed length, use that to allocate the necessary space, and then call it again to produce the result:

```
size_t length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s/rank_%d", path, i) + 1;

char path2[length];

snprintf(path2, length, "%s/rank_%d", path, i);
```

---

<sub>As for this being an intended way of using `snprintf`, yes, I'm pretty sure it really is. I'm basing that statement on conversations with Peter Seebach, who stated that when he joined the C standard committee, his primary intent was to get `snprintf` into the standard.</sub>

<sub>For that matter, I probably have to take a little responsibility for this approach, which I'll admit is something of a kludge. Back before `snprintf` had been invented, I wrote [a post on comp.lang.c.moderated](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c.moderated/kskTkzC8uEs/ZMKMd06yzm8J) showing how to do roughly the same thing even without `snprintf`. To do that, it opened a temporary file and wrote the output to it just to get the return value, then used `malloc` to allocate a buffer, and finally used `sprintf` to put the data into the buffer.</sub>

<sub>`snprintf` uses the same basic idea, but eliminates having to open an external file to use it. Despite that, it's still using pretty much the technique I posted, and as far as I know, I was the first one to suggest this general approach (though I can easily believe others may have thought of it first, but been too ashamed to post it).</sub>

Comment: `snprintf()` widely misunderstood: 3 issues here: `snprintf()` returns `int`, which can be negative and that should be checked.  The buffer size needed is `length + 1` (I see you have that now - better to use 1u for your code).  Pedantically the 2nd call _could_ have trouble too given preemptive locale changes (not likely) or volatile arguments.

Comment: @chux: Checking for a negative return value is the sort of error checking that's needed for real code but usually omitted from examples of the sake of clarity. The `+1` is already included in computing `length`. More generally, the basic design of `snprintf` really doesn't play particularly well with concurrency.

Comment: Reading the reference and seeing the code, I believe that this really is the design intend of `snprintf()`. Thank you! @chux: Negative values are only returned in case of an encoding error. Of course one should always check for all possible error cases, but this does not, for me, constitute a wide misunderstanding of this function (and this is an example). The buffer size was always given as `snprintf(...) + 1`, so that is correct. Changing variable values in between those calls is evidently bad.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `asprintf()`. It  will allocate need space as needed.  The only expected failure is running out of memory. It is not a standard C function, but available on many *nix systems. Otherwise:

Suggest 2 steps:

1. Scale the buffer to expected maximum size of the output per its arguments.  It should be OK if a few bytes too big.

   ```
   // e.g. size needed to print INT_MIN
   #define INT_SIZE_MAX (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 3)

   const char rank[] = "/rank_";
   char path2[strlen(path) + sizeof rank + INT_SIZE_MAX + 1];
   sprintf(path2, "%s%s%d", path, rank, i);
   ```
2. Insure no overflow with `snprinf()`

   ```
   int n = snprintf(path2, sizeof path2, "%s%s%d", path, rank, i);
   if (n >= sizeof path2 || n < 0) HandleRareFailure();
   ```

---

Reasons why `snprintf()` may fail:
1) Some sequence of bytes is invalid (encoding error).
2) Locale change caused commas to be added to `%d` --> "1,234,567,890".
<strike>3) Phase of the moon.</strike>  See below comments.

Comment: Phase of the moon what

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit A pedantic notion that `snprintf()`, a fairly complicated function, considering its potential extensions and locale issues, may fail with seemingly unusual data or correlations like the "phase of the moon".

Comment: I can assure you that `snprintf()`'s behaviour does not depend on the phases of the moon.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I concede to one who "races in orbit" that `snprintf()` does not depend on "phase of the moon".

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you! `asprintf()` looks very promising. I need to investigate if it is portable enough for my use case, though. Thank you for the second suggestion and its implementation. It has some problems (`%16d`, other datatypes, etc.) and seems rather unwieldy. I definitely understand the "phase of the moon" bit.

Comment: Notes: 1) `asprintf()` source code is readily available.  2) `"%16d"` is simply `max(16, INT_SIZE_MAX)`, etc.  `"%f"` is _the_ ugly one, something like  `DBL_MAX_10_EXP + 12` which can be 320+. 3) Time for some Pink Floyd [DSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Side_of_the_Moon)

Comment: Hehe, yeah, good music helps. But I'd rather not reinvent all that and possibly make a tiny off by one error somewhere, leading to stack corruption, which is the second worst kind of corruption.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin solution is good for VLA as you are using.  This approach works well with fixed buffer lengths.

Comment: If the buffer lengths are fixed, there is no need for any of these shenanigans, is there?

Comment: @Nils_M Yes. With fixed buffers, the maximum, if determinable is useful.  VLAs have a hidden implied maximum - typically the stack depth.  Note: VLAs are not required in C11 - so how to solve your task going forward?  An opening concern of your post was using 64-bit `int` vs 32- bit `int`.  That size difference can be handled at compile time with fixed size buffers.  Open ended array sizes with no upper bound are troublesome as short overly conservative ones.  If code truly needs _wide_ ranging size buffers, `asprintf()` is the way to go. VLAs chew up the stack in an uncontrolled fashion.

Comment: Ah, I see your concern. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score -6):

> Is there anything like this in the C standard, [or] in POSIX?

**No.**

> or somewhere else?

Well there's something like it in the Gnome library… :P

Comment: It seems like you know the answer but don't want to post it. No good.

Comment: @anatolyg: Um, what? This _is_ the answer. What's the problem?

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand that it's a reference to `g_printf_string_upper_bound`! Still, not a useful answer.

Comment: @anatolyg: In what way is it not useful? The question is: is there such a function in the C standard, or in POSIX. There is not. So, the answer is "no".

Comment: The correct answer is "yes", and the function in question is `snprintf`. So your answer is not only unhelpful, but downright wrong.